# PhoneGap login form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cordova, authentication

I'm trying to make a simple login form for my PhoneGap app. Since PhoneGap can't use any PHP on the client side I have to use AJAX to send the data to server. I found a simple PHP login tutorial but I really don't know how to get it to work with ajax.

I know how to post values to the PHP file, but how can I redirect the user to page if username and password are right or deny them from entering the site if the information is invalid?

This is the code I have right now:

JS

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: serviceURL + "login.php", 
    data: 'username='+username+'&password='+password,  
    cache: false,
        }
```

login.php

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['username'];
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
//  redirect 
header("location:settings.html");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

So how can I make the `if($count==1){....` part to take action on my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to set the expected dataType you want to retrieve (for example to html).
After that you have to also specify a function on the retrieved data after you suceeded retrieving the data...

Something like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    success: function(data) { // After retrieving the data from the php-file
    alert(data);}
    url: serviceURL + "login.php", 
    data: 'username='+username+'&password='+password,  
    cache: false,
    dataType:'html' // Expected return data type...
}
```

The **data** Variable contains the return string from the php file, so you have to echo something out with the php script, like "logged in" and then you have to filter / check this string with javascript...

Lucian